# Отменить событие Click на карте

Tags: яндекс-карты

При установленном флаге (истина) при клике на карте Яндекс выводится метка. Как сделать, чтобы при установленном флаге (ложь) при клике на карте Яндекс метки не выводились?

```
function clickkarti(estclick) {
    if (estclick) {
        // Слушаем клик на карте.
        myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
            coords = e.get('coords');

            myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
            // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
            myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
                getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
            });
            getAddress(coords);
        });
    }
    else {
        // Слушаем клик на карте.
        myMap.events.remove('click');
    }

}

estclick - переданное значение установленного флага (истина или ложь)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Решил следующим образом:


if (clickMap) {
    $("#clickkartis").attr('value', 'Показывать по клику метку');
    // Слушаем клик на карте.
    myMap.events.group().add('click', function (e) {
        coords = e.get('coords');
        CoordCklicka = coords[0].toPrecision(6) + "," + coords[1].toPrecision(6);
        if (marsh) {
            myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
            }, {
                preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption'
            });
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        };
    });
} else {
    $("#clickkartis").attr('value', 'Не показывать по клику метку');
    map.events.group().removeAll();
}
```